# What's the difference between var and _var in Rust?

Tags: rust

Given this:

```
fn main() {
   let variable = [0; 15];
}
```

The Rust compiler produces this warning:

```
= note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
= note: to avoid this warning, consider using `_variable` instead
```

What's the difference between `variable` and `_variable`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is an underscore at the front, which causes the Rust compiler to allow it to be unused. It is kind of a named version of the bare underscore `_` which can be used to ignore a value.

However, `_name` acts differently than `_`. The plain underscore drops the value immediately while `_name` acts like any other variable and drops the value at the end of the scope.

An example of how it does not act exactly the same as a plain underscore:

```
struct Count(i32);

impl Drop for Count {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping count {}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let _a = Count(3);
        let _ = Count(2);
        let _c = Count(1);
    }

    {
        let _a = Count(3);
        let _b = Count(2);
        let _c = Count(1);
    }
}
```

prints the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=14e49a59961d07f6e402&version=stable)):

```
dropping count 2
dropping count 1
dropping count 3
dropping count 1
dropping count 2
dropping count 3
```

Comment: Would you mind spelling out the difference with the bare underscore more clearly? It's a pretty big difference that one drops the object immediately while the other acts as a normal binding and drops it at the end of the lexical scope.

Comment: Another difference is that `let _x = y;` will _move_ `y`, so it's no longer valid after the statement, while `let _ = y;` won't move `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference between `_variable` and `variable` is that first one tells compiler not to give any warnings if we do not use it in our code. Example:

```rust
// src/main.rs
fn main() {
    let _x = 1;
    let y = 2;
}
```

Compiling `main.rs` gives:

```sh
warning: unused variable: `y`
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     let y = 2;
  |         ^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_y`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default
```

The more interesting case is when we are comparing `_` with `_variable`.

[Ignoring an Unused Variable by Starting Its Name with _](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#ignoring-an-unused-variable-by-starting-its-name-with-_):

> The syntax _x still binds the value to the variable, whereas _ doesn’t bind at all.

Consider example:

```rust
// src/main.rs
fn main() {
    let s = Some(String::from("Hello!"));

    if let Some(_s) = s {
        println!("found a string");
    }

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

When we try to compile `main.rs` we get error:

```sh
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `s`
 --> src/main.rs:8:22
  |
4 |     if let Some(_s) = s {
  |                 -- value moved here
...
8 |     println!("{:?}", s);
  |                      ^ value borrowed here after partial move
  |
  = note: move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: borrow this field in the pattern to avoid moving `s.0`
  |
4 |     if let Some(ref _s) = s {
  |                 ^^^
```

Aha! **The syntax _x still binds the value to the variable**, which means that we are **moving** the ownership of `s` to `_s`, thus, we can no longer access variable `s` anymore; which happens when we try to print value of `s`.

The correct way of doing the above is:

```rust
// src/main.rs
fn main() {
    let s = Some(String::from("Hello!"));

    if let Some(_) = s {
        println!("found a string");
    }

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Above code works just fine. `s` does not get moved into `_`, so we can still access it later.

Sometimes I use `_` with iterators:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _ = v
        .iter()
        .map(|x| {
            println!("{}", x);
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

Compiling gives result:

```sh
1
2
3
```

When doing more complex operations on iterable types above example acts as utility for me.